# Issues with push method on array

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a storage array and I able to use push method. But, in another part of my code, I have a memory array and I can't do that. What's the reason? Doesn't exist push method in memory arrays?

```
        Individual[] memory newPop = new Individual[](popSize);
        for(uint i = 0; i < popSize; i++){
            uint index1;
            uint index2;
            (index1, index2) = getIndex();
            Individual newIndiv = crossover(index1, index2);
            newPop.push(newIndiv);
        }
```

And the error:

[image: Error using push method]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keywords `push` and `pop` are applicable only for dynamic arrays.

Dynamic arrays can be declared only in storage (i.e., in global scope) AND with no predefined size.

For example: `uint256[] public arr`.

Aside from that, you've already allocated the local array `newPop` to the desired size, so why would you want to hypothetically use `push` and increase that size?

You should simply change this:

```
newPop.push(newIndiv);
```

To this:

```
newPop[i] = newIndiv;
```

Comment: Working, thanks a lot! I'm just starting with Solidity

Comment: By the way, is it possible to debug step by step in Solidity (like in Java, C++, etc.)?

Comment: @Joncarre: That's an IDE question, not a Solidity question. It is possible via Remix, Buidler, and perhaps a couple of other tools. You can also do it in the "old fashion" way and add `revert` or `require` statements in your code, in order to find the exact point of failure.